# How to detect that a profile has changed

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, my-site, timer-jobs, mysite

I need to detect when there has been an update on a user profile (my site) in SharePoint. I guess I will loop through all the user profiles in a timer job, and look after some proprerty. Any ideas of which property to look for ? Any tips on how this can be done in an optimized way ?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge there is no event associated with User Profiles. Hence there is no way we can define an event receiver.

As you suggested you need a timer service and then loop through the [profile change log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms549249%28v=office.12%29.aspx). Then take a decision based on that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a User Profile Change log that is maintained for 14 days by default. You can query it and determine what changed and even if your property of interest changed. In PowerShell you could get a service context and then do something like:

```
$manager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager $context
```

Then use one of the GetChanges overloads:

- GetChanges(), which retrieves all changes
- GetChanges(UserProfileChangeToken), which retrieves all changes from a given date or event
- GetChanges(ProfileBaseChangeQuery), which retrieves specific changes given a query object

Gary and I documented all this back in 2010, it should be the same in 2013. http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint-2010/monitor-sharepoint-user-profile-changes